# Intellij - Could not reserve enough space for object heap (2020.2)

Tags: intellij-idea, virtual-machine, heap-memory

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
> space for 2097152KB object heap

This error I'm receiving while trying run a simple test or anything else with Intellij 2020.2.

I decrease it to 1gb as I saw in other answers but the problem is still exist, although I have 32 GB RAM with a lot of free memory.

**Custom VM Options:**

-Xms128m

-Xmx1024m

**Memory Settings:** 1024 mb

**Build process heap size:** 1024 mb

**Memory Usage:**
[image: My memory usage - about 15 gb are free]

How can I solve this error?

P.S. I don't know where the '2097152KB' comes from..

Product Version: 202.6397.94

Restore IDE Settings not help.

**EDIT - IntelliJ Log (remove some lines):**

```
2020-09-02 16:11:27,788 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,837 [     49]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-202.6948.69, 25 Aug 2020 00:29) 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,840 [     52]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,840 [     52]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,840 [     52]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,842 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\jbr\\bin\server -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2020.2 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\{user}\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\{user}\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,842 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\jbr\\bin\server 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,842 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\jbr\bin 
2020-09-02 16:11:27,851 [     63]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_US JNU=Cp1252 file.encoding=Cp1252
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\log 
2020-09-02 16:11:28,495 [    707]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 644 ms 
2020-09-02 16:11:28,503 [    715]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2020-09-02 16:11:29,913 [   2125]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 12; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@6ca66aa2[Running, parallelism = 11, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@184debc3 
2020-09-02 16:11:30,112 [   2324]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: IDEA CORE (202.6948.69), com.intellij.platform.images (202.6948.69), JetBrains maven model api classes (202.6948.69), JetBrains Repository Search (202.6948.69), HTML Tools (202.6948.69), Perforce (202.6948.69), Refactor-X (202.6948.69), Subversion (202.6948.69), XPathView + XSLT (202.6948.69), XSLT Debugger (202.6948.69), Smali Support (202.6948.69), IDE Settings Sync (202.6948.69), Configuration Script (202.6948.69), Copyright (202.6948.69), CSS (202.6948.69), W3C Validators (202.6948.69), Less (202.6948.69), Sass (202.6948.69), Stylus (202.6948.69), Gradle (202.6948.69), Java (202.6948.69), Bytecode Viewer (202.6948.69), JUnit (202.6948.69), ZKM-Unscramble (202.6948.69), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (202.6948.69), Dependency Structure Matrix (202.6948.69), Java IDE Customization (202.6948.69), Java Stream Debugger (202.6948.69), Eclipse Interoperability (202.6948.69), Java Bytecode Decompiler (202.6948.69), Recommenders for Java and Python (202.6948.69), Windows 10 Light Theme (202.6948.69), Properties (202.6948.69), Ant (202.6948.69), UML (202.6948.69), Guice (202.6948.69), Java Internationalization (202.6948.69), UI Designer (202.6948.69), Velocity (202.6948.69), Resource Bundle Editor (202.6948.69), Machine Learning Code Completion (202.6948.69), Task Management (202.6948.69), Time Tracking (202.6948.69), FTP/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access) (202.6948.69), Gherkin (202.6948.69), Cucumber for Java (202.6948.69), Mercurial (202.6948.69), Webp Support (202.6948.69), EditorConfig (202.6948.69), Haml (202.6948.69), Terminal (202.6948.69), Git (202.6948.69), ChangeReminder (202.6948.69), Next File Prediction (202.6948.69), GitHub (202.6948.69), Performance Testing (202.6948.69), Shared Indexes (202.6948.69), SSH Remote Run (202.6948.69), WSL Support Framework (202.6948.69), Shell Script (202.6948.69), TextMate Bundles (202.6948.69), YAML (202.6948.69), Docker (202.6948.69), Microservices Application Configuration (202.6948.69), Settings Repository (202.6948.69), IntelliLang (202.6948.69), TestNG (202.6948.69), Code Coverage for Java (202.6948.69), Emma (202.6948.69), Groovy (202.6948.69), Cucumber for Groovy (202.6948.69), Maven (202.6948.69), AspectJ (202.6948.69), Gradle-Java (202.6948.69), Plugin DevKit (202.6948.69), Gradle Extension (202.6948.69), Frameworks Starters (202.6948.69), Gradle-Maven (202.6948.69), Reactive Streams (Reactor, RxJava) (202.6948.69), JavaFX (202.6948.69), Markdown (202.6948.69), Grazie (202.6948.69), JavaScript and TypeScript (202.6948.69), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (202.6948.69), TSLint (202.6948.69), Angular and AngularJS (202.6948.69), Database Tools and SQL (202.6948.69), Java SQL Libraries (202.6948.69), Persistence Frameworks (202.6948.69), Java EE Platform (202.6948.69), JavaScript Debugger (202.6948.69), Node.js (202.6948.69), Spy-js (202.6948.69), CoffeeScript (202.6948.69), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-6), Android (10.4.0.202.6948.69), Java EE: Persistence (JPA) (202.6948.69), Java EE: Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) (202.6948.69), Hibernate (202.6948.69), Java EE: Bean Validation (202.6948.69), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI) (202.6948.69), Helidon (202.6948.69), Java EE: Batch Applications (202.6948.69), Java EE: Application Servers Integration (202.6948.69), GlassFish (202.6948.69), WildFly (202.6948.69), Debugger Support for JSP (JSR45) (202.6948.69), Jetty (202.6948.69), Tomcat and TomEE (202.6948.69), WebSphere (202.6948.69), WebLogic (202.6948.69), Java EE: Web/Servlets (202.6948.69), Java Server Pages (JSP) (202.6948.69), Java EE: Server Faces (JSF) (202.6948.69), Application Servers View (202.6948.69), Java EE: Message Service (JMS) (202.6948.69), Java EE: WebSockets (202.6948.69), JBoss Frameworks Base (202.6948.69), Drools (202.6948.69), Arquillian (202.6948.69), Spring (202.6948.69), Spring Security (202.6948.69), Thymeleaf (202.6948.69), Spring Data (202.6948.69), Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS) (202.6948.69), Spring Web Services (202.6948.69), Grails (202.6948.69), FreeMarker (202.6948.69), Spring Batch (202.6948.69), Spring Messaging (202.6948.69), Spring Integration Patterns (202.6948.69), Spring WebSocket (202.6948.69), Spring OSGi (202.6948.69), Maven Extension (202.6948.69), HTTP Client (202.6948.69), Spring MVC (202.6948.69), Spring Web Flow (202.6948.69), Spring Boot (202.6948.69), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (202.6948.69), Quarkus (202.6948.69), Micronaut (202.6948.69), Java HTTP Clients (202.6948.69), OpenAPI Specifications (202.6948.69) 
2020-09-02 16:11:30,368 [   2580]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Exit: JBA_NOT_FOUND === 
2020-09-02 16:11:30,908 [   3120]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-09-02 16:11:30,924 [   3136]   INFO - m.intellij.util.io.StorageLock - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1959 
2020-09-02 16:11:30,940 [   3152]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - un-interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-09-02 16:11:31,092 [   3304]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2020-09-02 16:11:31,158 [   3370]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2020-09-02 16:11:31,391 [   3603]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-09-02 16:11:31,782 [   3994]   INFO - BridgeProjectLifecycleListener - Using legacy project model to open project 
2020-09-02 16:11:31,799 [   4011]   INFO - atform.impl.SharedIndexStorage - Shared Indexes Storage is opened: <empty> 
2020-09-02 16:11:32,248 [   4460]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2020-09-02 16:11:32,300 [   4512]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-09-02 16:11:32,721 [   4933]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [<Project>] 
2020-09-02 16:11:33,122 [   5334]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2020-09-02 16:11:33,400 [   5612]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
2020-09-02 16:11:35,733 [   7945]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2020-09-02 16:11:35,908 [   8120]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.ui.KotlinConfigurationCheckerComponent$projectOpened$1@1669daaa 
2020-09-02 16:11:37,950 [  10162]   INFO - penapi.application.Experiments - Experimental features enabled for user: wsl.p9.support, wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser, inline.browse.button, linux.native.menu, recent.and.edited.files.together, show.create.new.element.in.popup, copy.reference.popup, new.large.text.file.viewer, property.value.inplace.editing, terminal.shell.command.handling 
2020-09-02 16:11:38,157 [  10369]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode 
2020-09-02 16:11:38,400 [  10612]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 7238 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,469 [  11681]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,489 [  11701]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 63 millis (read time: 3) 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,577 [  11789]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar ignored === 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,618 [  11830]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - Mapped Roots: 1 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,816 [  12028]   INFO - .OnDiskSharedIndexChunkLocator - Scanning C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\shared-index for shared indexes... 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,920 [  12132]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 12 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,934 [  12146]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.25.1.windows.1 
2020-09-02 16:11:39,958 [  12170]   INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe: 2.25.1.0 (MSYS) 
2020-09-02 16:11:40,288 [  12500]   INFO - ProjectRootPostStartUpActivity - C:/CodeCloud/OCP/ocp-infra/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2020-09-02 16:11:40,369 [  12581]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 1921ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 0/2 sluggish, 1/2 very slow 
2020-09-02 16:11:40,561 [  12773]   INFO - llij.database.util.SqlDialects - SQL dialects initialized in 1 ms 
2020-09-02 16:11:40,826 [  13038]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 9187 ms 
2020-09-02 16:11:41,050 [  13262]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 2649 
2020-09-02 16:11:41,636 [  13848]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Sent token to maven server 
2020-09-02 16:11:41,743 [  13955]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1487ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
2020-09-02 16:11:42,090 [  14302]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-09-02 16:11:46,201 [  18413]   INFO - gnostic.WindowsDefenderChecker - Windows Defender status: not used 
2020-09-02 16:11:48,899 [  21111]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace:connect timed out 
2020-09-02 16:11:49,205 [  21417]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 7460ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-09-02 16:11:49,240 [  21452]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index 
2020-09-02 16:11:50,198 [  22410]   WARN - reporter.KotlinReportSubmitter - connect timed out 
2020-09-02 16:11:50,513 [  22725]   INFO - red.download.SharedIndexLookup - Connection expired by timeout at https://index-cdn.jetbrains.com/v1/jdk/3d7ad7bbcee6fd9a3348b63fcef6c9bd73069698/index.json.xz for JdkIndexRequest(sdkName=1.8, hash=3d7ad7bbcee6fd9a3348b63fcef6c9bd73069698, aliases=[1.8.0_221, 1.8], innerVersion='v1', kind='jdk'). connect timed out 
2020-09-02 16:11:50,819 [  23031]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace:connect timed out 
2020-09-02 16:11:50,973 [  23185]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 4ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-09-02 16:11:52,627 [  24839]   WARN - util.DeprecatedMethodException - The default implementation of method 'com.intellij.execution.configurations.ConfigurationFactory.getId' is deprecated, you need to override it in 'class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.nodejs.protractor.KotlinProtractorConfigurationType$1'. The default implementation delegates to 'getName' which may be localized but return value of this method must not depend on current localization. 
com.intellij.util.DeprecatedMethodException: The default implementation of method 'com.intellij.execution.configurations.ConfigurationFactory.getId' is deprecated, you need to override it in 'class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.nodejs.protractor.KotlinProtractorConfigurationType$1'. The default implementation delegates to 'getName' which may be localized but return value of this method must not depend on current localization.
    at com.intellij.util.DeprecatedMethodException.reportDefaultImplementation(DeprecatedMethodException.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.ConfigurationFactory.getId(ConfigurationFactory.java:80)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImplKt.getFactoryKey(RunManagerImpl.kt:1313)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImplKt.access$getFactoryKey(RunManagerImpl.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.getConfigurationTemplate(RunManagerImpl.kt:326)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.createConfiguration(RunManagerImpl.kt:251)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.cloneTemplateConfigurationStatic(RunConfigurationProducer.java:258)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.cloneTemplateConfiguration(RunConfigurationProducer.java:248)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationFromContext(RunConfigurationProducer.java:97)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.findOrCreateConfigurationFromContext(RunConfigurationProducer.java:198)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.doGetConfigurationsFromContext(PreferredProducerFind.java:110)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.getConfigurationsFromContext(PreferredProducerFind.java:93)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.ConfigurationContext.getConfigurationsFromContext(ConfigurationContext.java:360)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.ExecutorAction$Companion.computeConfigurations(ExecutorAction.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.ExecutorAction$Companion.getConfigurations(ExecutorAction.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.ExecutorAction$Companion.access$getConfigurations(ExecutorAction.kt:28)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.ExecutorAction.getActionName(ExecutorAction.kt:97)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.ExecutorAction.update(ExecutorAction.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.LineMarkerActionWrapper.update(LineMarkerActionWrapper.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.doUpdate(ActionUpdater.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$new$1(ActionUpdater.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.callAction(ActionUpdater.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$new$2(ActionUpdater.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.update(ActionUpdater.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandGroupChild(ActionUpdater.java:297)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$doExpandActionGroup$19(ActionUpdater.java:276)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.concat(ContainerUtil.java:1611)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.doExpandActionGroup(ActionUpdater.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandActionGroup(ActionUpdater.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandActionGroup(ActionUpdater.java:160)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$expandActionGroupWithTimeout$11(ActionUpdater.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.withTimeout(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandActionGroupWithTimeout(ActionUpdater.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandActionGroupWithTimeout(ActionUpdater.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenu(Utils.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPopupMenuImpl$MyMenu.show(ActionPopupMenuImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.invokePopup(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:2120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.mousePressed(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:1836)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.processMousePressed(EditorImpl.java:3959)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.lambda$runMousePressedCommand$0(EditorImpl.java:3831)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.runMousePressedCommand(EditorImpl.java:3836)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.mousePressed(EditorImpl.java:3764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:288)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6651)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2020-09-02 16:11:54,112 [  26324]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=infra, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\CodeCloud\OCP\ocp-infra)RunManager took 65 ms 
[Delete some lines]
2020-09-02 16:11:56,231 [  28443]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get features from Marketplace:connect timed out 
2020-09-02 16:11:56,287 [  28499]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2020-09-02 16:11:56,288 [  28500]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2020-09-02 16:11:56,288 [  28500]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2020-09-02 16:11:59,559 [  31771]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace:connect timed out 
[Delete some lines]
2020-09-02 16:12:31,659 [  63871]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,733 [  63945]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - StubIndexExtension-s were unloaded 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,739 [  63951]   INFO - redIndexChunkConfigurationImpl - Shared index chunks shutdown was performed successful 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,739 [  63951]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,739 [  63951]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,873 [  64085]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,874 [  64086]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Start shutting down C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\index\rep.names 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,875 [  64087]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Finished shutting down C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\index\rep.names 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,879 [  64091]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-09-02 16:12:31,885 [  64097]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

### Update

I have not succeeded to resolve the issue but found a **workaround** after I found other projects are working well. I recreate the project (in my case delete local directory and clone it again from Git) – Now all working fine, don’t know why it’s happen or how to fix.

Comment: Could you please share logs ("Help | Show Log in...")? Probably 32-bit JDK version is used insted of 64-bit.

Comment: @y.bedrov thank you, actually I just uninstall the IDE (and now download it again). I'll update the question once I'll finish...

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you again, reinstall not helps. I copied the log (after I delete the old one and delete some lines from the new becuase I reached the maximum post length)